# Two one-to-one relationships in EF core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, relationship

I'm trying to configure a one-two-one relationship twice for an entity with the following classes.

```
public class Team 
{
    ...
    public virtual TeamGraphic TeamLogo { get; set; }
    public virtual TeamGraphic TeamPlayer { get; set; }
}
public class TeamGraphic
{
    ...
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

TeamGraphics will be image data.

In the datacontext class

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Team>(t =>
{
    t.HasOne<TeamGraphic>(g => g.TeamLogo)
    .WithOne(t => t.Team);

    t.HasOne<TeamGraphic>(g => g.TeamPlayer)
    .WithOne(t => t.Team);
});
```

So to put it in words. A team can have one logo, and a team would have one player (image).

But when I try to do a migration, I get the error:

```
Cannot create a relationship between 'TeamGraphic.Team' and 'Team.TeamPlayer' because a 
relationship already exists between 'TeamGraphic.Team' and 'Team.TeamLogo'. Navigations can 
only participate in a single relationship. If you want to override an existing relationship 
call 'Ignore' on the navigation 'Team.TeamPlayer' first in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

Is this at all possible to do?

Comment: See if this helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73446805/ef-core-creating-a-link-between-items-in-the-same-table/73447619#73447619

I would just add a Id for the Logo and another for the Player in the Team table, and use the `HasForeignKey` of the fluent API to assign them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is full explained on error: *"Navigations can only participate in a single relationship."* That means you should to create a second `Team` on `TeamGraphic`

```cs
public class TeamGraphic
{
    ...
    public virtual Team TeamFromTeamLogo { get; set; }
    public virtual Team TeamFromTeamPlayer { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Team>(t =>
{
    t.HasOne<TeamGraphic>(g => g.TeamLogo)
    .WithOne(t => t.TeamFromTeamLogo);

    t.HasOne<TeamGraphic>(g => g.TeamPlayer)
    .WithOne(t => t.TeamFromTeamPlayer);
});
```

It has sense. If you only have one reverse navigation, `TeamGraphic.Team`, is ambiguous. "Which one"?

Comment: Thanks for getting me unstuck. If you see it it somehow makes sense, but first to see it...

Comment: Thanks so much for this, had the exact same issue but for a User that could have 2 types of documents (Avatar and a Resume) in a 1:1 relationship